# Rotating a selection of features around their individual centroid rather than the combined centroid

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, digitizing, rotate

The rotate feature in QGIS 3 allows you to select multiple features at once and rotate them around the centroid of their combined geometries, as found in [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#rotate-feature-s).

You can also use an anchor point different from the default feature centroid by pressing Ctrl or if you hold Shift before clicking on the map, the rotation will be done in 45 degree steps, which can be modified afterwards in the user input widget.

I would like to rotate a selection of multiple features around each features **individual centroid**?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

- Check `Rotate` tool in the QGIS's Toolbox. Leave `Rotation anchor point` blank.

[image]

- Or in edit mode, select features, enter `Rotate` in search box in status bar and use `Rotate` tool under `Edit Selected Features`. Again leave the second box blank,  so that the tool will use individual centroid of selected features.

[image]